# Cerrar una pestaña de una pág. web HTML en IOS

Tags: javascript, html, html5, ios

Estoy desarrollando un página y hice una pestaña de un formulario normal y en la que los términos y condiciones son mostrados en una pestaña aparte, sin embargo el botón que coloqué de cerrar pestaña en términos y condiciones esta con JavaScript y solo me funciona en Android, cuando se intenta ejecutar en un Iphone desde el navegador no funciona el botón,

Me gustaría saber que necesito para que funcione (la opción para cerrar pestaña) en ambas plataformas adjunto el código que actualmente estoy utilizando.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
        function closed() { 
           window.open('','_parent',''); 
           window.close(); 
        } 
        </script>
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:closed();">Volver al Formulario</a>
```

Comment: Si utilizas Chrome en iPhone puedes ver los errores que te da la página. Puedes subir ese error para que la comunidad te pueda ayudar.

Comment: Al parecer ese script de cerrar pestañas fue quitado de la mayoría de los navegadores porque era potencialmente peligroso, ya que se podía utilizar con malas intenciones, razón por la que no se ejecuta, tendré que buscar otra solución, gracias.